# PyPDF2 fill Arabic is not visible while English is fine

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to fill a PDF with Arabic and English. English is fine but Arabic is not visible after writing. It's showing on click.

I am translating the English into Arabic text using Google API.

I have also tried appearance functionality, fillpdf, PyPDF2 and pdfrw libraries.

No luck.

Comment: These kind of language issues are often font issues.  You may need to set or add the font for the PDF.

Comment: You may want to have a look at PyMuPDF - it supports right-to-left scripted fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after adding the proper font for Arabic text. The Ubuntu Doc viewer was not showing the text but in Adobe reader its just perfect.